# Direct wrapper to function in C++ class

Tags: c++, linux, windows, dynamic-library

I am trying to make a function which can be called as a class member. Here is some code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class CTest;
void CTestSum(CTest* ptr, int a, int b);

class CTest{
public:
    int i;
    void sum(int a, int b);
    CTest() : i(0), sum(CTestSum)
    {
    }
};

void CTestSum(CTest* ptr, int a, int b)
{
    ++ptr->i;
    cout << (ptr->i)+a+b << endl;   
}

int main() {
    CTest instance;
    instance.sum(2, 4);

    return 0;
}
```

Eventually, the function will end up in a dll or library. See also http://ideone.com/csueum
Compilation failed with the following error message:

```
prog.cpp: In constructor 'CTest::CTest()':
prog.cpp:12:18: error: class 'CTest' does not have any field named 'sum'
  CTest() : i(0), sum(CTestSum)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The type of a variable in C++ can never be a function type. Your `CTest::sum` is a member function, not a data member.

Comment: I know but when ``sum`` was pointer to function, it didn't have pointer to class instance because it didn't parse as method but as variable. When I called ``instance.sum(2, 4)`` then program was pushing only 4 and 2 excluding pointer to class instance on stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sum` is not a data member of the class, so you cannot initialize it in the constructor's member intialization list.  There is no need to initialize `sum()`, simply give it a body that calls the real function as needed, eg:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class CTest;
void CTestSum(CTest* ptr, int a, int b);

class CTest{
public:
    int i;
    void sum(int a, int b) { CTestSum(this, a, b); }
    CTest() : i(0)
    {
    }
};

void CTestSum(CTest* ptr, int a, int b)
{
    ++ptr->i;
    cout << (ptr->i)+a+b << endl;   
}

int main() {
    CTest instance;
    instance.sum(2, 4);

    return 0;
}
```

Your DLL can then implement and export the `CTestSum()` function as needed, and your `CTest` class can be a header-only implementation for better portability across different compilers.